# Use <?php as plain text in a .php file?

Tags: php

I have this.php:

```
<?php

//some code

?>
Here goes the text that is plain text.
Whenever you use <?php in a .php file it precedes the php code that will be parsed and interpreted by php.
```

As you may have guessed, this file gives an error and refuses to run correctly. I don't want to use HTML entities as the result file isn't used as HTML. What are my options other than storing the string **`<?php`** in a variable?

Comment: If the result is not supposed to be used as HTML, then using `<?php` once for PHP code and once "plain" is ambiguous. Does whatever you're using the result as not support escape sequences of any sort?

Comment: @deceze, no just plain text, I'm generating PHP code from PHP itself.

Comment: Woah man, codeception! ;o)

Comment: @deceze, what's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @deceze — I once had the “joy” of dealing with a build time Perl script that generated a run time PHP script that generated a client side JavaScript that generated HTML. It was horrible.

Comment: @kavoir.com You may have some catching up to do on some Hollywood movies of recent years... Rest assured it's nothing significant I'm expressing above. ;)

Comment: @Quentin, I mean this to be a semi-cache system that the parent PHP code read some complex MySQL queries and then dump the results to a child PHP file that can then be read by the application. The parent PHP only runs once a while, it's a major performance bliss. I thought it's a good thing?

Comment: @Quentin Sounds like the plot of Inception 2 - A Programmers Nightmare.

Comment: @kavoir.com — Sounds like you'd be better off using something like memcached.

Comment: I concur. Generating code is virtually always a bad idea, with the only exception being something like scaffolding tools which a developer uses to get started quickly. A regular application shouldn't be generating new code on the fly, there's always a way to do without that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate it programatically using a string literal.

```
<?php echo "<?php"; ?>
```

Comment: I suppose then it's best to store it in a variable? As I'm generating PHP code from PHP and there will be more than one occasions to use <?php in plain text. I thought there were some native ways to do this, such as a backslash or something.

Comment: PHP has no special "Output the string `<?php`" mechanism, and plain text files have no way to escape the text, so there isn't a native way.

Comment: [Heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) might be what you are looking for. It is good for a long text without the trouble of escaping quotations or anything else.

Comment: Sidenote: Only `Here goes the text that is plain text. Whenever you use` will echo on screen. The complete `Whenever you use <?php in a .php file it precedes the php code that will be parsed and interpreted by php.` will only appear in the HTML source, whether that is OP's wish or not.

Comment: I do not agree with this answer because you might have a big chunk of html/php code that you need to display. Using echo will complicate it too much. A simple answer is posted.

Comment: @DeeJay' — You can just put the big chuck outside the `?><?php` and only go into that for echoing out the string `<?php` itself. More importantly, *there is no other way* (except variables, but they aren't significantly different).